# Is LINQ Where extension method optimized for SortedDictionary?

Tags: .net, linq, sorteddictionary

Folks,

If I call the LINQ Where extension method, does it take advantage of the sorting in SortedDictionary or does it traverse each KVP and make the comparison?  Is there an advantage to using SortedDictionary for the search-by-criteria scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: How can `Where` take advantage of that? I'd expect `Max` and `Min` to work better on a sorted collection, but `Where` can only get a limited benefit: maybe when the predicate is `.Where(kvp => kvp.Key < 5)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, whilst LINQ methods attempt a few basic casts (ie to ICollection when a length estimate is needed), they cannot begin to cast the IEnumerable to every .net collection out there to see if they can make use of that collection's properties.

However as you know the properties of your SortedDictionary source, could you use TakeWhile or SkipWhile instead of Where?

Comment: Thanks for responding!  How would TakeWhile help?  TakeWhile is a LINQ method right?  So it has no awareness of the sorting?  I'm trying to somehow take advantage of the sorting to get all values that are greater-than, less-than, or equal-to a given value (these are standard types like int, string, etc.)

Comment: Consider using a sorted dictionary of names to get all names < "Thomas". You could use Where - however this would compare every single name against "Thomas", many needlessly. Alternatively you could use TakeWhile, which only evaluates the conditional until the first failure ("Thomas" or above), reducing the count somewhat. Or faster again you could use a binary search to find the index of the first that fails the conditional, and then use Take(n) to return every element prior. Just a few different ways you can use the properties of a SortedDictionary to speed up your query.

Comment: Welcome. I just realised binary searches don't apply to a SortedDictionary, but you get the idea :).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell from examining the source code (via Reflector), no special handling is performed for `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: thanks!  Any suggestions on how to solve for my scenario?  I'm looking to sort a set of keys once-and-for all, then I want to query those keys for criteria like >, <, =, and return the resulting value in the KVP.  Trying to get this to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on the behavior of SortedDictionary's enumerator implementation. Use Reflector there to see what behavior that enumerator exhibits.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Linq query will enumerate the collection as a sequence of KeyValuePair objects and apply the predicate to each. Therefore, you won't get the benefit of the fast lookup that a SortedDictionary provides in this case.

However, you should realize that it's not really possible to use the efficient key lookup of a dictionary (sorted or otherwise) to perform this particular type of query, because the efficient key lookup will resolve to a single entry. That's because duplicate keys are not allowed in the data structure, so for a given key that can be used to do fast lookup you will only ever resolve to a single resulting value, not a sequence.

Therefore, the scenario does not really make sense.

Comment: I can guarantee no duplicate keys.  Does the scenario makes sense now? =)

Comment: No, because .Where() is designed to produce a sequence, but looking up a key in a dictionary is guaranteed to return exactly _one_ item, not a sequence of items. So it's not clear why you would even try to use .Where() - just use the ContainsKey method to check if the value exists in the dictionary.